# Getting Machine Serial Number With WMI Class

Tags: c#, wmi, wmi-query

I wrote this part of c# WMI Code for getting MotherBoard serial Number

```
ManagementObjectSearcher ComSerial = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_BaseBoard");

foreach (ManagementObject wmi in ComSerial.Get())
{
    try
    {
        MainBoard.Text = wmi.GetPropertyValue("SerialNumber").ToString();
    }
    catch { }
}
```

But in fact i want to learn PC(Machine) Serial Number(Written On PC Box'es top,bottom,right,left,front or back side).

In which table of Win32 has contains this information? I hope you understand me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The serial number is in the [Win32_BIOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394077%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class.

Comment: In my case the value was not the good one ... still searching

Comment: What do you mean not good? Sounds like your manufacturer didn’t set the serial number. Who makes the computer you are testing?

Comment: MSI. Its strange because after re-verifying, the app from msi tell me this serial number to, but the laptop sticker show an other s/n. And the one on the box is the same as the one on the laptop sticker.