# How to get mechanical keyboard serial number

Tags: c#

yesterday I encountered a big problem.My business requirement is to obtain the serial number of the mobile hard disk,so I use WMI to solve this requirement.However,I can not obtain serial number of mechanical keyboard using this method.So,is there anyone else who knows how to get the serial number of mechanical keyboard using C# ? Thanks very much.

Comment: Hope you're looking for this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27196822/getting-machine-serial-number-with-wmi-class).

Comment: I've never tried getting serial number but for something as simple as scan codes It will be pain to code it in C#, I would suggest you to make some lower level library and use it with the C#. Start by checking the communication on the port from the beginning.

Comment: @m.rogalski thanks for your advice.Do you have a specific solution？

Comment: @AshishSrivastava I've seen this answer,but it could not work.Do you have any other idea?

Comment: @flynn I'll check that out and if I find the source I'll post it back here.

Comment: @m.rogalski thx

Comment: If you are in this millenium, have a look at [getting the serial number from USB devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723449/retrieving-the-serial-number-of-a-usb-keyboard-under-windows). If your keyboards are coal powered or otherwise from the last millenium... that's going to be tough.

Comment: How about accessing it from RegistryKey entries?

Comment: @AshishSrivastava can you give example code ?

Comment: Something like Derek W has suggested in his [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28200014/5588347) or may be the this msdn [post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172516(v=vs.90).aspx)